# Why are titles suddenly so hard to write?

Tags: support, question-quality, title

I just tried to post a question, and there's suddenly something that is checking titles for "quality". It took me three tries to get past it, and there was precious little information about what was required to have a "quality" title.

Can we smarten this up, or at least provide some better hints about what's being requested?

Answer (score 24):

Your first two titles appear to have been,

1. > why is pytype not finding this error?

   Which error is that?
2. > why does pytype not flag my type error?

   Slightly more specific ("type error") but still pretty general.

The title that got through was,

> why does pytype not flag an integer/string type clash?

Ah, now *that's* specific! This is something that someone else with the same question could probably find if they were looking for it, and a description that someone with an answer might reasonably see and be interested enough to click through...

And that's the reason for the check: to try to encourage folks to write titles that will both aid them in getting answers, and aid others with the same questions in finding the same answers.

The message you should've seen is,

> Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

This is triggered by a few different heuristics; the common problem tends to an overly-vague title though, so that's what I was going for. There is additional guidance on the linked help center page.