# Reject question titles with no English letters in them, warn about titles with too few a-z compared to other letters

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, languages, ask-question-form

There was yet again [a question posted in a wrong language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58255118/918959) (now deleted, i.e. 10k+). Since there are [other checks already in place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390121/why-are-titles-suddenly-so-hard-to-write), **perhaps it would be worthwhile to require that a question title on English-speaking Stack Overflow must contain several letters `[a-zA-Z]` in the title**. In this case all characters in the title *"Заполнение диагоналей трехмерной матрицы"* (translation: *"Filling the diagonals of a three-dimensional matrix "*) were either white space or Cyrillic letters.

As a further improvement the **body** of that particular question had 3 letters `N` of the Latin script in the body, and that would have failed the dummiest validation, but perhaps there should be a simple frequency analysis - if too many `\w+` words outside the code blocks have letters not in `[a-zA-Z]` then at least a warning should be displayed - this should also catch even those occasional Việtnamese ones that I've seen.

Comment: seeing such questions hanging open for days (and sometimes even getting answers, go figure) always makes me think that [meta-tag:triage] review is somehow terribly broken

Comment: That question simply needed to be migrated to ru.stackoverflow.com. This should trivially be automatable.

Comment: @smci and what if it was written in Ukrainian...

Comment: Antti there is no ua.stackoverflow.com, and even if there was, Cyrillic-reading users could trivially easy figure out what to do with it. What is your proposal (other than automating preventing people asking Cyrillic questions)? What should SO autosuggest to them?

Comment: As my question reads my proposal is to automate Stack Overflow to reject titles that do not have English letters in them and to state - in English - that the site is English-language only and hence question titles must be written in English.

Comment: @smci The guidance has always been "don't migrate crap" (I might be paraphrasing). So unless we have created an automated quality verifier that also understands all of the languages supported on the various language-specific SO sites, I'm guessing it's not so trivial...

Comment: @HereticMonkey The key point to the "don't migrate crap" policy is that it applies to content that's *already been posted* to the wrong site. An automated filter like the one smci proposed would *automatically* detect that it's Cyrillic and then create the post on ru.stackoverflow.com *from the outset*.

Comment: @TylerH the thing is I've *never* seen a good question posted in wrong language to Stack Overflow. Or maybe the standards over there are just a tad lower. My filter would forbid from such posts ever landing. Hey, the instruction message could even point to other language sites, there aren't too many. Let the user figure out which one is appropriate.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala FWIW I agree with your proposal, I just think smci's addition would be *even better*. (I have seen a few good questions get asked here, and then deleted and re-asked on the appropriate site after being pointed out in comments).

Comment: @TylerH Then I guess it's less migration than simply redirection, if the post never shows up on SO. Still seems like we're pushing potential crap on another site that doesn't necessarily want to deal with it either. I mean, we could technically detect that questions that ask for a review of code (a search of "please review my code") and post those to [codereview.se], but I doubt they would be pleased with the result...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, though CR isn't a good comparison, because they aren't "SO but in another language" - they require specific things (like not an MCVE but rather the whole program, for one thing). Each of the foreign language SOs, to my knowledge, all have the exact same rules as the English-speaking SO for topicality/scope. But I do agree that we could and should be doing a lot more to block a lot of questions from being posted (e.g. anything with the phrase "best practices" used in interrogative form, for one).

Comment: @HereticMonkey and Tyler: since I don't read Cyrillic or speak Russian, I didn't know if this was nonsense. It's unclear what Antti (or the rest of you) are actually proposing *should* be done with this post, other than complaining it shouldn't be allowed on the English-speaking site. Obviously crap shouldn't be posted, but given SO can't manage to police the English-language site adequately, I wouldn't hold my breath on implementing crap-detection heuristics in Cyrillic.

Comment: @smci I think the proposal is clear; just as we don't allow questions which have the word "error" in a short title, we prevent questions where the title and/or non-code portions of the body is solely in a character set outside of, say, ISO 8859-1. That said, I agree with not holding our collective breaths considering SO, inc, is busy making sure scores can't (appear to) go below 0...

Comment: @HereticMonkey: the proposal is totally unclear, for the 90+% of us who don't read Cyrillic! We don't know whether *"Заполнение диагоналей трехмерной матрицы"* means *"Filling the diagonals of a three-dimensional matrix "* any more than *"Scrape hot girls' profiles from social-media"*. Context! So I just added a translation. Next time, give context. Or else we might start posting posts in Kyrgyz then say "But of course it's clear!"

Comment: @smci I don't read Cyrillic either... Not sure why you thought I did, or why it matters to the proposal. It was clear to me from the start that the proposal was what I said it was, but to each their own...

Comment: @HereticMonkey: because it could be *on-topic* or *off-topic*; and it's hard to automatically determine that across [multiple languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285041/are-there-stack-exchanges-in-different-languages), with arbitrarily low error-rate. You wouldn't suggest we should allow (off-topic) posts like (in Cyrillic) *"How to hack Pentagon"* would you?

Comment: @smci I'm suggesting we don't allow posts with (only) Cyrillic on stackoverflow.com at all, that's the point of the proposal, as I read it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: but you haven't *actually proposed what we should do with it*, so this is only at best half a proposal. Should it be auto-migrated to the corresponding SO site for that language? after being automatically checked for on-topic? Do you think it should just be rejected? accepted but promptly deleted? (very rude to user, if they have to repost it). And what about the case of 200 languages where we don't have a SO in that language? What's your proposal?

Comment: The title of this question is, "Reject questions with no English letters in title, warn about those with too few".

Comment: @HereticMonkey: *"suggesting we don't allow posts with (only) Cyrillic on stackoverflow.com at al"* Nonsense. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ exists and has had posts in Cyrillic for years. So you misunderstood the proposal. Because it's incomplete.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: "reject" on which site? On the English-language stackoverflow.com, but not on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ ? And like I'm asking, what specifically happens to a "rejected" post? Is it deleted? automigrated to the corresponding langiage site? Specifics missing

Comment: @smci I very purposefully put stackoverflow.com and *not* ru.stackoverflow.com. They would be rejected on the English-only Stack Overflow site, obviously. This is meta.stackoverflow.com, after all, not meta.ru.stackoverflow.com. What happens to posts with "error" in a short title? Nothing, because there are no (new) posts with that problem -- they are prevented from being posted in the first place.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Still not good enough. Many people would read 'SO' as *.stackoverflow.com (or even "all of SE"). And most SO users (incl. me) are unaware (until today) of which specific foreign language versions of SO exist. FYI the Meta site for https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ is https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/ . Useful to crosslink there from here, and vice versa. I repeat, this is at best half a proposal (consider how unwelcoming it is in its current incarnation for Cyrillic users)

Answer (score 21):

Bump. This is becoming more and more a problem over time, there are misguided Russian-speakers several times a day now. Any post that largely consists of Cyrillic should be either rejected, and/or the author should be made aware that [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) exists with a custom message.

Comment: They actually tried to give a [warning for questions that might fit on a foreign language SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323249/6083675). I don't know if it's still active. Unfortunately, Ukrainian uses the same letters as Russian so it's possible that such a message wouldn't always be helpful, but it couldn't be less helpful than allowing them to post anyway. Plus I can't help but think that we can use that one header that tells you what language a user prefers to maximize accuracy.

Answer (score 21):

[image: Example of Title Validation Result]

Ok, so I added a new question title validation that titles must have at least *one* character between a-z.  It's a pretty minimally intrusive rule; there could be more done to require multiple characters / words, etc, but this should catch the most blatant of cases and have very few false positives.

This has been rolled out to *all sites* except the following:

- [Japanese Language Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)
- [Japanese Language Meta Stack Exchange](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [Korean Language Stack Exchange](https://korean.stackexchange.com/)
- [Korean Language Meta Stack Exchange](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ukrainian Language Stack Exchange](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ukrainian Language Meta Stack Exchange](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)
- [Русский язык Meta](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [Russian Language Meta Stack Exchange](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [Russian Language Stack Exchange](https://russian.stackexchange.com/)
- [Chinese Language Stack Exchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/)
- [Chinese Language Meta Stack Exchange](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
- [スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Stack Overflow на русском Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)
- [Mi Yodeya Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)
- [Code Golf Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

This was based on this query I ran on how positively received questions without a latin a-Z character were per site:

[image: query results showing percent of questions well received per site]

This will end up applying validation rules to some existing questions that will apply on next revision.  So if people edit the following questions, they'll have to also provide an updated title.  In most places, these questions would benefit from revision or adding clarifying copy alongside the current title.

- [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21,... - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416058/1-5-9-13-17-21)
- [2.9999999999999999 >> .5? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173070/2-9999999999999999-5)
- [71,000 + 85 = 71,084? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157324/71-000-85-71-084)
- [101 - 6 + 10 = 97 - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231222/101-6-10-97)
- [система не обновляется - elementary OS Stack Exchange](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19076/%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f)

In the future, we may do some language detection and try to route russian askers to the russian stack site (for example), but that'll be a different ticket.

### Update 3/14

Updated copy to "English" and add link to [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/209031). Thanks to Laurel & Makyen for the suggestions!

Comment: Is it intentional that these validation rules are not applied on rollbacks?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that's intentional, @gparyani. Someone who wants to rollback an inappropriate edit should be able to do so immediately, without having to worry about rewriting the post to meet our current standards.

Answer (score 13):

Here’s [a query I wrote](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1121930) to find all existing titles that don’t contain A-Z:

```sql
select id as [Post Link] from posts where title not like'%[a-zA-Z]%'
```

As you can see, there are a handful of (what I consider) legitimate titles with no alphabetics, but not enough to stop this FR from being a good idea (not just here but also on most of the other sites in the network).  There’s also a trivial way to change these titles to actually contain words (e.g. “*Why is it that* 185.3 + 12.37 = 197.67000000000002?”)

Strangely enough this query also turns up [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57835785/revisions) posted completely in English where the title was edited into Russian(?) days after it was posted without anyone noticing. (Which I have never seen before but would have been caught by a title filter like this.)

Comment: Of course the filter could be changed to "if there are any letters then there should be Latin letters" if those types of titles are considered worth keeping

Comment: I'd consider *all* of the titles gotten from that query unclear, and deserving of being rejected in favor or a well-formed question sentence.